# SQL Server UPDATE FROM INNER JOIN error - Foreign key error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have the following scenario:

**TABLE_B**

- ID is the primary key
- `ID_MASTER`, `COL` is a foreign key referencing `TABLE_MASTER(ID, COL)`

Sample data:

```
    ID  ID_MASTER  COL  TYPE
   --------------------------
    1     1000  0      A
    2     1000  0      A
    3     2000  0      B
    4     2000  0      B
```

**TABLE_MASTER**

- `(ID, COL)` is the primary key

SaAmple data:

```
    ID   COL   DESC
   --------------------
    1000 0     XXX
    2000 0     AAA
    3000 0     BBB

--##SOURCETEMPTABLE

    FROM_ID   TO_ID
    1000     3000
```

I'm trying to run this UPDATE:

```
UPDATE P
SET P.ID_MASTER = N.TO_ID,
    P.COL = 0
    /*SELECT N.TO_ID,* --JUST FOR CHECK THE ROWS BEING UPDATED*/
FROM TABLE_B P
INNER JOIN ##SOURCETEMPTABLE N ON N.FROM_ID = P.ID_MASTER
WHERE P.ID_MASTER = 1000
```

It returns an error "foreign key conflict"

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FKTABLE_B_ID". The conflict occurred in database "base_x", table "dbo.TABLE_MASTER"

But, when I run the same statement using a "static" value instead of `N.TO_ID`, it works normally:

```
UPDATE P
SET P.ID_MASTER = 2000, --static value
    P.COL = 0
    /*SELECT N.TO_ID,* --JUST FOR CHECK THE ROWS BEING UPDATED*/
FROM TABLE_B P
INNER JOIN ##SOURCETEMPTABLE N ON N.FROM_ID = P.ID_MASTER
WHERE P.ID_MASTER = 1000
```

Comment: You have 3000 in your ##SOURCETEMPTABLE and use the static value of 2000. These are not 1:1 comparisons, are they? Can you post the actual table structure and keys?

Comment: In summary, in this case, I have to change all 1000 values to the correpondenting value in ##sourcetable, In static case, 2000 is a acceptable value because the table_master contains it.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=44a7e89196333e8aead6906da96113d8) so what aren't you telling us? I'm guessing you have a value in `##SOURCETEMPTABLE` that isn't in `TABLE_MASTER` and that's what is causing it.

Comment: @scsimon but the WHERE clause makes the join to `##SOURCETEMPTABLE`  pretty superfluous.   Any value other than `1000` would be ignored.

Comment: Ah good catch @TabAlleman

Comment: Sorry for the bad example, i was trying to figure out the answer, and I Found it. And was a terrible mistake. The example above, was modified (because I could not expose the real table names and values) and I know that was very poor. Sorry. Sometimes you've got a second point of view from someone, all the trouble was a mismatch type from ##sourcetemptable, the id column was declared as float, and in the real scenario the master_table id is a Varchar.... beginner error. Thanks for all support.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is not reproducible.   I ran the following test and received the message (2 row(s) affected) with no error message.   You must be doing something other than what you describe in your question:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_MASTER (
    ID int
,   COL int
,   CONSTRAINT PK_TM
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, COL)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE_MASTER VALUES 
(1000,0)
,(2000,0)
,(3000,0)
;

CREATE TABLE TABLE_B (
  ID int
, ID_MASTER int
, COL int
, CONSTRAINT PK_TB
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
, CONSTRAINT FKTABLE_B_ID
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_MASTER, COL)
  REFERENCES TABLE_MASTER(ID, COL)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE_B VALUES
(1,1000,0)
,(2,1000,0)
,(3,2000,0)
,(4,2000,0)
;

CREATE TABLE Source (
 FROM_ID int
, TO_ID int
)

INSERT INTO Source VALUES (1000,3000);

UPDATE 
        P
    SET
        P.ID_MASTER = N.TO_ID,
        P.COL = 0

    /*SELECT N.TO_ID,* --JUST FOR CHECK THE ROWS BEING UPDATED*/
    FROM TABLE_B P
    INNER JOIN Source N
        ON N.FROM_ID = P.ID_MASTER
    WHERE P.ID_MASTER = 1000
```